# how to deploy an EKS cluster application on AWS marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, aws-marketplace

I want to make my application available on the AWS marketplace. My application is composed of an EKS cluster and then multiple helm chart used to deploy my micro-services (using argocd at the moment).

I am not sure which delivery method to use, I want to use a cloudformation template stack to deploy the EKS infrastructure and the helm chart ?

Should I use a lambda function to call my application deployment service once the initial cloudformation stack is deployed (EKS cluster created) ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the application running in your account or in your customer's account? If it's in your account- it's a SaaS- regardless of how you architect it. So you need to select delivery method -SaaS and use the integration guide based on your pricing model: https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsmp-loadforms/AWS+Marketplace+-+SaaS+Integration+Guide.pdf

If your application runs on your customer's account, meaning when they launch it, a cloudformation stack deploys an EKS customer on your customer's account, then in that case you need a container as a delivery method- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/container-based-products.html